# Table of contents spacing between text and dotted line in 'Tab' - paragraph styles

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, paragraph-styles, table-of-contents

I added dotted lines to my table of contents using the tab section in my assigned paragraph style. I want to determine the space between the text and the dotted line as well as the space between the dotted line and the number. I am not sure how to adjust this in paragraph styles. 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is a rather old question but since nobody answered you, I'll take a go.
You have actually reached the limit of using the leader feature.
If you want to do it properly (yeah!), you need to forget about using this leader thing. Here's my suggestion:

First, create a character style with underline format.
Use Grep style to apply this character to the tabs. Reminder: \t is tab metacharacter.
In the TOC options, add the desired fixed space (em, en, or whatever you wish) before and after the tab.

Now you're (almost) good to go.

I say almost because you might encounter other issues.
E.g. What about multiple lines entries?
Also, if you want the exact same spacing before and after the tabs, it means your stroke style needs to be adjusting space between dots. Meaning you can end up with squeezed, or even overlapping dots.

When it comes to this kind of formatting, many things have to be considered, like right indents. Do not hesitate to report back if you need deeper support. (Note that my preferred formatting is to use... two tabs in the TOC options, haha ^^)